# Multiple client server android

Tags: java, android, sockets, server, client

I'm doing a desktop server application in java with multiple android clients, each one with a thread. I'm using sockets to provide the communication.

Until now, clients are sending messages to the server and then do something based on server response.

But now I need that server send a message to a specific client and I don't know how.

Could you help me please?

Thanks

**Server class**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        boolean listening = true;

        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444)){

            while(listening){
                new ServerThread(serverSocket.accept()).start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 4444");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

    }
}
```

**ServerThread**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ServerThread extends Thread {

    private Socket socket = null;

    public ServerThread(Socket socket) {
        super("ServerThread");
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    public void run() {

        try (
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                    socket.getInputStream()));
        ) {
            String inputLine, outputLine;
            GameProtocol gp = new GameProtocol();
            outputLine = gp.processInput(null);
            //System.out.println(outputLine);
            //out.println(outputLine);

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                //System.out.println(outputLine);
                outputLine = gp.processInput(inputLine);
                System.out.println(outputLine);
                out.println(outputLine);
                if (outputLine.equals("Bye"))
                    break;
            }
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**TcpClient class**

```
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

/**
 * Created by andrecorreia on 03/06/16.
 */
public class TcpClient {

    public static final String SERVER_IP = "10.0.2.2"; // computer IP address
    public static final int SERVER_PORT = 4444;

    // message to send to the server
    private String mServerMessage;
    // sends message received notifications
    private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
    // while this is true, the server will continue running
    private boolean mRun = false;
    // used to send messages
    private PrintWriter mBufferOut;
    // used to read messages from the server
    private BufferedReader mBufferIn;

    /**
     * Constructor of the class. OnMessagedReceived listens for the messages received from server
     */
    public TcpClient(OnMessageReceived listener) {
        mMessageListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Sends the message entered by client to the server
     *
     * @param message text entered by client
     */
    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        if (mBufferOut != null && !mBufferOut.checkError()) {
            mBufferOut.println(message);
            mBufferOut.flush();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Close the connection and release the members
     */
    public void stopClient() {
        Log.i("Debug", "stopClient");

        // send mesage that we are closing the connection
        //sendMessage(Constants.CLOSED_CONNECTION + "Kazy");

        mRun = false;

        if (mBufferOut != null) {
            mBufferOut.flush();
            mBufferOut.close();
        }

        mMessageListener = null;
        mBufferIn = null;
        mBufferOut = null;
        mServerMessage = null;
    }

    public void run() {

        mRun = true;

        try {
            //here you must put your computer's IP address.
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

            //InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

            //create a socket to make the connection with the server
            Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.92", SERVER_PORT);

            try {
                Log.i("Debug", "inside try catch");
                //sends the message to the server
                mBufferOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

                //receives the message which the server sends back
                mBufferIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                // send login name
                //sendMessage(Constants.LOGIN_NAME + PreferencesManager.getInstance().getUserName());
                //sendMessage("Hi");
                //in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server
                while (mRun) {
                    mServerMessage = mBufferIn.readLine();
                    if (mServerMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                        //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                        mMessageListener.messageReceived(mServerMessage);
                    }

                }
                Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + mServerMessage + "'");

            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);

            } finally {
                //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
                // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.
                socket.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);

        }

    }

    //Declare the interface. The method messageReceived(String message) will must be implemented in the MyActivity
    //class at on asynckTask doInBackground
    public interface OnMessageReceived {
        public void messageReceived(String message);
    }
}
```

**Main Activity**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    public static TcpClient tcpClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new ConnectTask().execute("");

        // Set up click listeners for all the buttons
        View playNowButton = findViewById(R.id.playNow_button);
        playNowButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        View optionsButton = findViewById(R.id.options_button);
        optionsButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        View helpButton = findViewById(R.id.help_button);
        helpButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        View exitButton = findViewById(R.id.exit_button);
        exitButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        //---------------------------------------------
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i;
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.playNow_button:
                i = new Intent(this, PlayNowActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.options_button:
                i = new Intent(this, OptionsActivity.class);
                tcpClient.sendMessage("options");
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.help_button:
                i = new Intent(this, HelpActivity.class);
                tcpClient.sendMessage("help");
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.exit_button:
                finish();
                break;
        }
    }

    public class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,TcpClient> {

        @Override
        protected TcpClient doInBackground(String... message) {

            //we create a TCPClient object and
            tcpClient = new TcpClient(new TcpClient.OnMessageReceived() {
                @Override
                //here the messageReceived method is implemented
                public void messageReceived(String message) {

                    //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                    publishProgress(message);

                }
            });
            tcpClient.run();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        /*View view = adapter.getChildView(0, 0, false, null, null);
        TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.betChildOdd);
        child2.get(0).get(0).put("OLD", text.getText().toString());
        child2.get(0).get(0).put(CONVERTED_ODDS, values[0].toString());
        child2.get(0).get(0).put("CHANGE", "TRUE");
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();*/
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi. Could you tell me what's wrong with that, please? Or how could I do it correctly? Thanks

Comment: Your server needs 2 threads per client or a dedicated send thread. You're currently stuck in  `in.readLine()` and can't send. With an extra thread to send you can queue up messages from outside (using a `BlockingQueue`, classic producer-consumer scenario) and decide at any point to send data while the reading code doesn't need to interrupt waiting.

Comment: @zapi thanks for helping me. Could you tell how could I do 2  threads per client, please? Thanks

Comment: @ScaryWombat There is nothing wrong with that pattern. The user simply starting a thread for each client socket connection. And yes it is an infinite loop but the call serverSocket.accept() is a blocking call and wait for a new socket to connect.

Comment: @gipsy sorry it looked to me like he was creating a new Thread - my bad

Comment: @agfac zapl's comment should take you to the right path. What triggers the message to client from the server? If you want to send messages to a specific client you have to start tracking the client socket connections with some sort of identifier for each client socket.

Comment: @gipsy this application is a turn based game. So, at a specific moment of the game I need to send a message for a specific client saying it's his turn (and jump to another activity on android) and another message to the other client saying his turn is over (and jump to another activity). Is it a correct way if I have an ArrayList to keep the threads and access them to send the messages? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution you suggested could be something like this?

Thanks

```
public class Server {

    private static ArrayList<ServerThread> playerList;
    private static LinkedBlockingQueue<Object> messages;
    private static GameProtocol gp ;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        playerList = new ArrayList<ServerThread>();
        messages = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Object>();
        gp = new GameProtocol();

        Thread accept = new Thread() {
            public void run(){
                while(true){
                    try{
                        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
                        ServerThread player = new ServerThread(serverSocket.accept(), gp);
                        playerList.add(player);
                        player.start();

                    }
                    catch(IOException e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
                }
            }
        };

        accept.setDaemon(true);
        accept.start();

        Thread messageHandling = new Thread() {
            public void run(){
                while(true){
                    try{
                        Object message = messages.take();
                        // Do some handling here...
                        System.out.println("Message Received: " + message);
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException e){ }
                }
            }
        };

        messageHandling.setDaemon(true);
        messageHandling.start();
    }
}
```